# Deleted all my migrations including __init.py__

Tags: django, import, django-views, django-forms, django-migrations

I am a beginner using Django. I have recently been working on a website that has a few different pages. I reference a couple of views from other apps in urls.py. One app I used to take inputs and make some calculations, so it had  some forms defined. It was all working fine and I was able to import the views fine, but I changed one of my form field names. This caused some problems because I was storing these values in a database. That made sense to me because I had already saved some data with the previous naming convention and now I had changed it. So, I figured that deleting my database and migrations would allow me to start over and start a new database with my updated fields. I messed up though because I read that I should not have deleted my **init.py** file in my migrations folder.

I have tried re-doing my migrations with makemigrations and migrate but I keep getting an error saying that no changes are made and no new migrations show up in my folder. Also, now when I look in my urls.py file, the imported views and apps are showing up with a red underline and says "import package".

I have also tried reverting my code back and was able to get the migration files back, but the same error was shown in my urls.py file.

I have tried just about everything I could find online, but am now thinking that I may just have to recreate these apps.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Are you using `sqlite` Database ?

Comment: Yes I am @PrOgRaMmEr

Answer (score 1):

First of all, to rename a form field, just change it in the models and then make and apply migrations. Django should detect the renaming of an existing field and create `migrations.AlterField(...)` statements (you can inspect the migration files that were created, and freely delete them if they are not yet applied/migrated).

First, please check if adding the empty file called `__init__.py` to the migration folder solves the problem. This is a python requirement, to let the interpreter know that the folder contains a python module.
Also if you have downloaded the project from somewhere, you need to have the existing migrations. Deleting them and recreating them yourself will likely fail.

After that just try running

```
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate
```

If there are still no changes, check if there are migrations applied to your database by looking at the django_migrations table or by running this command:

```
python manage.py showmigrations
```

If this did not help, try to start with a clean project:

1. Backup all your code changes and revert to the starting point, the `__init__.py` file should be back and you should also delete the database (db.sqlite3)
2. run the migrate command
3. add all your code changes
4. check if your code changes have new migration files, they could cause problems. If you have not created or modified them manually, you can delete and let Django recreate them

Answer (score 0):

You could try this code:

python manage.py makemigrations (name of the django_app that contains the model)